# iOS 7: Is it possible to make UIView's background transparent to show the blurred background?

Tags: iphone, background, ios7, translucency

I ask this question after seeing apps like Reminders or Safari's tab view using this.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [slashgear.com](https://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/icloud_tabs-580x324.png))</sub>

As you can see there is a translucency between the app and the home screen. Is there anyway to achieve this in iOS 7? Is it a private api?

Answer (score 1):

No such luck sadly - it's a private API.

Comment: Wow...i really wished they would let us use that API